# graphviz in a virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, graph, virtualenv, graphviz

My project runs in a virtual environment with `Python 3.5` in Ubuntu 16.04. I want to visualize a graph output using `graphviz` (installed inside the virtual environment). But when I run the `render` function to visualize the graph, an error comes :

```
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg', '-O', 'deBruijn.svg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

How do I fix this issue by just modifying my virtual environment, without installing any package in the base OS (Ubuntu 16.04) ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install http://www.graphviz.org/.

From [manual](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/blob/master/docs/manual.rst):

> After installing Graphviz, make sure that its bin/ subdirectory containing the layout commands for rendering graph descriptions (dot, circo, neato, etc.) is on your systems' path: On the command-line, dot -V should print the version of your Graphiz installation.

Comment: I didn't quite get the bin subdirectory part. I installed Graphviz, I navigated where it was installed and there I only found "include" directory, not a bin directory. Can you kindly explain what you meant by bin directory?

Comment: There must a `bin/` directory. How did you install `Graphviz`?

Comment: I downloaded and installed graphviz-2.38.msi from the official https://graphviz.gitlab.io website.

Comment: I just installed the msi. The directory `bin` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin`